# The best way to load development seed data into Postgres in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, docker, devops

I'm trying to improve the Docker on-boarding experience in a project of mine, I'm using `pv` to indicate progress of loading data into Postgres, it works, and it's pretty nice. The problem is that once the data is loaded, indexes need to be built and that takes time. During this time the progress bar is at 100% and nothing appears to be happening. I'd like to have it animate somehow to indicate that something is happening.

Here's a rough example of what I'm going for:

[image]

The thing that's got me like  is how do I do this within a pipe? I guess I could create a script and pipe through that, use `pv` and somehow detect when the file IO has completed and then switch up the output to the post-100% animation.

This is the current command:

`pv tmp/latest.sql | psql -q -h db -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB > /dev/null`

I plan on moving it into an entrypoint script soon, so don't get too hung up on it being a "one liner". Anyways, I figured I'd just ask all you super smart people on here and see what happens.

Oh, this is the project that it's for: https://github.com/heycarsten/lcbo-api

Thanks for your help, everyone!

**UPDATE**

I'm not set on some "fancy" progress indicator, try to unfocus on that. My goal is to get data into the dev database from a dump on S3 (or wherever). And for the experience to be communicated to the developer clearly, which in the case of this project will be a lot of people learning to program for the first time.

Just because in the past I always did it this way: boot the app, create the schemas, load in the data, doesn't mean it's the only option, I'm aware of that and I'm absolutely open to other options.

If you think I'm ignorant or whatever, you're right! I'm new to the whole Docker thing, but so far I've been really enjoying it.

My objectives are:

- The seed data is updated periodically
- There is a solid amount of data, due to the nature of the project and it is important that all of this data is available
- There will also be a task within the Rails app to re-seed the database

If there is a pure Docker way to do this I'm all ears, but I don't understand how data can go from an image into a volume?

Comment: I have the strong feeling that you got your docker design wrong. Why should a docker-entrypoint do that? You should focus on that rather than on a fancy progress bar if you aim for a successful docker onboarding

Comment: Oh I think I'm following... so this stuff is going into Postgres, so I should do something with the Posgres image so that the data is already available, and I don't have to resort to doing it after the containers boot? If that's the design I should be going for can you direct me to an example somewhere? @hek2mgl

Comment: I wouldn't couple the postgres container with the initialization process of your applications db. Either run the initialization from the host, like `docker exec CONTAINER_NAME psql ...` or run this from another container which runs the psql command upon start of the postgres container and exits after that. The first would be probably the simplest